# How to get valid json from external file?

Tags: php, json

I trying to get json data from website. In the first link, it returns blank.
But in the second, it returns json.

Someone know how I could to do to get json data from the first link?

Before access this code, please login in this link:
https://loginfree.globo.com/login/438
user: cartolaewlfa@gmail.com
pass: cartoletasfc

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://cartolafc.globo.com/time/claudioivp-allianz/atletas.json?rodada_id=12"></iframe>
<?php
$file = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://cartolafc.globo.com/time/claudioivp-allianz/atletas.json?rodada_id=12"));

print_r($file);

echo "casa";
?>

<iframe src="http://cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/filtrar.json?page=1&order_by=preco&clube_id=277"></iframe>
<?php
$file = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/filtrar.json?page=1&order_by=preco&clube_id=277"));

print_r($file);

echo "casa";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry about my answer, I read your post twice and still didn't get it. I'm apparently having a bad night.

Comment: I still don't get why do we need to login to that website. You know that php is server side and is not able to use the browsers credentials right? aff tinha que ser desse cartolafc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently the first json URI requires the user to be logged in the website otherwise it redirects you to the homepage and the second one appears to be open to everyone.

The only solution I see here is to use curl (or any other method you'd like) to emulate a browser and follow the login process for that website, sending in your login, password and any other info that it requires. Then you can catch the cookies that it will generate. After you get the cookies you can keep then stored in a cookiejar file or a database.

With these cookies you'll be able to retrive the json file, you can send them through a `file_get_contents` by using a `stream_context` object or if you're using curl there is the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`

Of course these cookies will expire. Just set-up a verification process in which it gets new cookies if the stored ones have expired.

If the contents of this json file do not update with a high frequency or if it's not really important for the users to get these updates right away you could just keep a copy of this json file in your server without any access restriction.

It would be silly but in case that domain is YOURS (or you have access to it) just cut out the login verification in that file??

Comment: Thanks by your reply.
please login in this link: https://loginfree.globo.com/login/438 user: cartolaewlfa@gmail.com pass: cartoletasfc

after login, access in directly the link: http://cartolafc.globo.com/time/claudioivp-allianz/atletas.json?rodada_id=12

to access by browser, it's that ok. The problem is in retrieve it by file_get_contents =/

Comment: (just explaing the above in his language) Amigo, foi oq eu expliquei na resposta acima, esse arquivo aí requer autorização pra ser acessado, essa autorização é verificada por meio de cookies que o navegador envia para o site depois de vc fazer login. Pelo PHP você não tem acesso a esses cookies pois eles estão no navegador do usuário. Então vc tem q dar um jeito de pegar esses cookies no lado do servidor e depois envia-los no `file_get_contents` por meio de um objeto `stream_context`. Ou então simplesmente mantenha uma copia do arquivo json no seu servidor.